# Errno 2 No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmp3v35kv5z.upload.pdf'

Tags: python, file-upload, django-2.0

In my project, I need to upload many files for which size can go upto 50-60 MB. I am using Django file field to upload files. But when the file size is above 2.5MB it gives me this error
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmp3v35kv5z.upload.pdf'

I tried different file sizes. Files < 2MB work just fine

Settings.py looks like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "uploads")
CONTENT_TYPES = ['image', 'document']
# 2.5MB - 2621440
# 5MB - 5242880
# 10MB - 10485760
# 20MB - 20971520
# 50MB - 5242880
# 100MB 104857600
# 250MB - 214958080
# 500MB - 429916160
MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = "104857600"
```

view.py looks like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['fileToUpload']:
    myfile = request.FILES['fileToUpload']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
    path = fs.url(filename)

    student_roll_no = request.POST.get('roll_no')
    document_type = request.POST.get('doctype')
    department = request.POST.get('department')
    title = request.POST.get('title')
    subject = request.POST.get('subject')
    date_of_submission = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    document_code = student_roll_no+'_'+document_type
    ...

    Document.objects.create(code = document_code, document = request.FILES['fileToUpload'], path = path, date_of_submission = date_of_submission, type = document_type, title = title, department = department, subject = subject, updation_allowed = '0')
```

Expected Result: File upload Success!
Current Result: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmp3v35kv5z.upload.pdf'

Edit 1:
The file is being uploaded to the uploads folder but while making an entry in the database it throws an exception with the above error.

Edit 2:
Found the solution. Just needed to add the following line to the settings.py file
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 5242880

Comment: You have to edit "apache" (maybe you server) to allow upload files bigger than 2 MB, is duplicated question

Comment: edit "apache"? how do we do that with django

Comment: then look django config, i didnt read  you was using django

Answer (score 0):

2.5 MB is the default memory limit on Django, as it is in-memory.

[Upload Limit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#where-uploaded-data-is-stored)

> "...On a Unix-like platform this means you can expect Django to
>   generate a file called something like /tmp/tmpzfp6I6.upload. If an
>   upload is large enough, you can watch this file grow in size as Django
>   streams the data onto disk."

Run to monitor file size, `watch -n 1 ls -alh '/tmp/tmp3v35kv5z.upload.pdf'`

You can also use a custom FileHandler to control file limit as per your need.

[FileHandler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/files/uploads/#writing-custom-upload-handlers)

Comment: I read about the upload limit. I don't want to control the file size as such. I just need my program to handle large size files. Can you provide a link any such example

Comment: and upload those files